# aws cdk aws_iam.User with passwordResetRequired=True how to initialPassword

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm setting up my AWS user management in the aws_cdk now, and I have a bit of trouble understanding the aws implementation of "initialPassword" for newly created users.

according to the documentation around "passwordresetrequired" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.User.html#passwordresetrequired

I should
`If this is set to 'true', you must also specify "initialPassword".`

But there is no such explicit "initialPassword" that can be set as far as i can see?

So does it mean I should just set a regular password for the user? and how will this behave when I update this stack or the managed_secret later, will all the passwords for all users be changed again?

Example of how I could do this:

```
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager/Secret.html
myonetimepass = aws_secretsmanager.Secret(
    self,
    'onetimepass',
    description='Onetime password for new users',
    # encryption_key=
    # generate_secret_string=
    removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    # replica_regions=
    # secret_name=
)


for user in team.users:
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/User.html
    aws_iam.User(
        self,
        user,
        groups=[newgroup],
        # managed_policies=
        password=myonetimepass.secret_value,
        password_reset_required=True,
        # path=
        # permissions_boundary=
        user_name=user,
    )
```

But is this really the right way to set a "initialPassword"?

Answer (score 1):

That's a way to do it but unless you have a step to email them the initial password it won't be of much use.  Typically you will use a deterministic initial password based on the user information they have.  For example, the initial might always be first 5 characters of last name + last 5 of social.  Or you could do first 5 of last name + dob as yyyymmdd. Then you just let your users know what the initial password format is.

Comment: Yes i have a automated way to email the user the content of the aws_secret. The real question here was should i just set "password" + reset_required, and this will then be the magic "initial_password" that the aws api doc is talking about?